# Google Apps Script server error occurred: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, gmail, runtime-error

I recently started occasionally getting server errors from one of my scripts I set to run automatically every half hour. It doesn't happen consistently (sometimes with days between errors, other times just a few hours). It had been running without a hitch for nearly a year up until now, which is why I am surprised it would suddenly start spitting errors. When I checked the logs it says the error that occurred was "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED". I found other posts about similar errors, but none of the ones I found seemed to answer my question (and/or were resultant of problematic code). My code is really simple, so I don't see anything that could possibly be causing problems:

```java
function markArchivedAsRead() {  
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread -in:inbox -is:snoozed');
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
  if (threads.length == 1) console.log("1 thread marked as read");
  else console.log(threads.length + " threads marked read");
}
```

Is this error something on Google's end?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a new issue in the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

These unexplained errors likely occur when you are using the V8 Runtime engine.

Open your `appsscript.json` file, change the `runtimeVersion` to `DEPRECATED_ES5` and the errors should no longer happen.

Comment: Any idea why that might be causing intermittent errors?

Comment: There are still bugs in the V8 runtime that have caused several new errors and this is one of them.