# unexpected error DEADLINE_EXCEEDED google spreadsheet onOpen() trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, exception, add-on

I have a google spreadsheet addon, Formula Tracer Sidebar, published on the Google workspace marketplace.

Every once in a while, the following error entry is in the gcloud log explorer.

**Sample log entry**

```
{
"insertId": "***",
"jsonPayload": {
  "serviceContext": {
    "service": "***"
  },
  "context": {
    "reportLocation": {
      "functionName": "[unknown function]",
      "filePath": "[unknown file]"
    }
  },
  "message": "We're sorry, the JavaScript engine reported an unexpected error. Error code DEADLINE_EXCEEDED."
},
"resource": {
  "type": "app_script_function",
  "labels": {
    "invocation_type": "simple trigger",
    "project_id": "formula-tracer-side-bar",
    "function_name": "onOpen"
  }
},
"timestamp": "2022-04-05T18:14:51.408Z",
"severity": "ERROR",
"labels": {
  "script.googleapis.com/user_key": "***",
  "script.googleapis.com/project_key": "***",
  "script.googleapis.com/deployment_id": "***",
  "script.googleapis.com/process_id": "***"
},
"logName": "***",
"receiveTimestamp": "2022-04-05T18:14:51.690091557Z"
}
```

exception occurred in the onOpen trigger where the the addon menu items are added

The `resource.labels` values:

```
"invocation_type": "simple trigger",
"function_name": "onOpen"
```

**onOpen:**

```
function onOpen(e){
  let menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem('Trace precedents', 'tracePrecedents');
  menu.addItem('Trace dependents', 'traceDependents');

  menu.addToUi();.
}
```

I have never experienced or actually see the error nor know how to reproduce it. I can only can such log files entries.

I found some a bit older posts with similar errors not identical though, suggesting this is because of the V8 run time bug. for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769651/google-apps-script-server-error-occurred-deadline-exceeded) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65104577/how-to-avoid-deadline-exceeded-when-were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-pleas).

[This](https://support.google.com/code/answer/70638?hl=en) article by Google Calendar support gives a kind of general explanation and solution (resend request).
Assuming this is a similar situation, maybe even the exact same V8 bug, I'm thinking of the following implementation

1. wrap add menu with try-catch ans extract to separate function `_addmenus()`
2. check `_addmenus()` return value. if not success sleep and try again
3. max attempts = 10

**New onOpen:**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let done = false;
  const maxTimes = 10;
  const timeout = 200; //ms
  let i = 1;

  //loop to try add menus
  while(!done && i <= maxTimes){
    //add menus
    done = _addmenus();

    //if failed - sleep before next try
    if (!done && i < maxTimes){
      Utilities.sleep(timeout);
    }

    i++;
  }

  //done loop - log failure
  if (!done){
    console.error("failed to add FT menu items");
    const msg = `Unexpected error while loading spreadsheet addon. `
            +`Please try to reload the spreadsheet. `
            +`If the problem continute, wait a few minutes and try again.`;
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
 }
}

function _addmenus() {
  let success = false;
  try {

    let menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
    menu.addItem('Trace precedents', 'tracePrecedents');
    menu.addItem('Trace dependents', 'traceDependents');
    menu.addToUi();
    success = true;

  } catch (e) {
    console.error("SS onOpen", e);
  }

  return success;
}
```

I do not even know if the user is actually aware of the exception (that is, gets some error feedback) or that the result is just addon menus items are not being added to the spreadsheet, but  I'd like to show a message with `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);`.
Maybe this will also fail. but it is a try to handle the issue.

Is this a good way to handle this situation?
Is it OK to sleep while onOpen()?

### Update:

I reported a bug in *Goolge's Issue Tracker* [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230353471)

Comment: I've seen a lot of similar reports regarding this, and you could do the same as recommended here on this [public issue ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229628572) to change your runtime version to the Deprecated ES5 and further observe if this would help. In any case that this happens again, you could file your own bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905). Just make sure you check every now and then for further updates so that your ticket won't be closed.

Comment: @DiegoSanchez I might open a bug, but changing the runtime version is a bit scary. I can not reproduce the issue, so I can not really check / test this change. On the other hand, I am afraid of other unexpected influences on the app behavior. I can of course test in general that it works, but the addon is already live for few months, and doing so feels risky. Coding wise, are there necessary code modification  that might be needed, or that both versions (V8 and the previous one - not sure what it would be) fully support same features syntax? what do you think about what I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how and if this will actually solve this, only time will tell.

[Google recommends](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230353471) to handle such case like suggested above using `sleep` and try again.